# how to save m4a file in userDefauls and to present it in a table view-ios swift 3

Tags: swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have developed a recording and play the voice of the user and I need to save in in User Defaults and in the next screen to present all the recording data in a list view

my question is how to save m4a file? and how to present the data later on?

```
var soundRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
var soundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

var audioFileName = "sound.m4a"
let arrayOfRecords = [""]

//recording issues

let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: Float(44100.0) as Float),
                      AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) as Int32),//change to 850k vs 25Mb at (kAudioFormatAppleLossless)
                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(value: 1 as Int32),
                          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue) as Int32)]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupRecorder()

    buttonPlay.isHidden = true
    readableText()        

    //audio speaker not mic option

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)    
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    textViewTest.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}


/////recording
@IBAction func ActionRecord(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.titleLabel?!.text == "Record"{
        buttonPlay.isHidden = false    
        if isTimerRunning == false{
        }
        sender.setTitle("Stop", for: UIControlState())    

        //stop recording + save
        UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayOfRecords, forKey: "userRecord")
        // defaults.object(forKey: "userRecord")//print   
    }
    else{
        print("record")
        stopTimer()
        soundRecorder.stop()
        sender.setTitle("Record", for: UIControlState())
        buttonPlay.isEnabled = true    
    }    
}

//play record
@IBAction func ActionPlay(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.titleLabel?!.text == "Play" {                
        butttonRecord.isEnabled = true
        sender.setTitle("Stop", for: UIControlState())    
        preparePlayer()
        soundPlayer.play()    
    }
    else{
        soundPlayer.stop()
        sender.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState())    
    }    
}

//    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userRecord") as? String{
//            print("your record has been saved")
//        }
//   }
//HELPERS
func preparePlayer(){        
    do {
        try soundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: directoryURL()!)
        soundPlayer.delegate = self
        soundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        soundPlayer.volume = 1.0
    } catch {
        print("Error playing")
    }    
}

func setupRecorder(){        
    let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    //ask for permission
    if (audioSession.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:)))) {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
        if granted {
            print("granted")         
            //set category and activate recorder session
            do {            
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                try self.soundRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: self.directoryURL()!, settings: self.recordSettings)
                        self.soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
            } catch {            
                print("Error Recording");        
            }        
        }
    })
}

}

func directoryURL() -> URL? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as URL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
    return soundURL
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    buttonPlay.isEnabled = true
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    butttonRecord.isEnabled = true
    buttonPlay.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState())
}

}
```

Comment: you should encrypt audio into base_64 and store into Userdefaults

Comment: I would suggest to follow the approach of saving the .m4a file into documents directory and save its path...

Comment: @AhmadF finally someone who does know this kind of files should not be in UserDefaults... a lot of people do not know UserDefaults should be used to save defaults settings, like language, in it. Not audio/passwords/sensitive data.